# Setting random string as id

Tags: python, django

I want to set a random string as ID in django. This is what I have currently:

```
def pkgen():
    from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
    pk = get_random_string(length=10, allowed_chars=u'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789')
    return pk

class Note(models.Model):
    noteID = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True, default=pkgen)
    note = models.TextField()
```

The problem is that before I didn't put `pkgen` and I just put ID, so when I go to my admin page for the note, it just says

```
TypeError: id() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

Changing it to `pkgen` and redoing migrations just makes it crash and give the `TypeError` above. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: I think we are missing details ... really this should work ... your problem is coming from somewhere else ...also `import uuid;random_string = uuid.uuid4()` is a good way to generate a unique id string

Comment: What do you mean by just put ID? Do note that in Python there is a built-in function [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id).

Comment: What i meant is that before I didn't have `default=pkgen` in `noteID`, I just put `default=id` and I think that messed up the database or django or something :S

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set a random string as a django object's id, you should use the [UUIDField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield)

from the documentation:

> *A field for storing universally unique identifiers. Uses Python’s UUID class. When used on PostgreSQL, this stores in a uuid datatype, otherwise in a char(32).*

Comment: I will strongly second this ... however my suggestion in the comments also provides this